# Does blocked/yield thread can be reused by OS for different task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool, blocking

have maybe stupid question, but when we block or yield thread (in this case I use c++11) can OS reuse core to run another thread.
I mean, we have threadpool (4 thread) and 10 tasks which depends on task A on some levels. And after running our app, threadpool took 4 tasks from queue (but not the A task) and on some moments all thread start to wait for finishing A. Does app will hang, or OS just swap core to next task like in single core system?
Sorry for my English ^_^

Comment: from what I understood, you have a threadpool that consumes tasks from a queue, and can take 4 at a time, and starts a new task when one is finished.
From that the OS does not control your tasks, and there will not be new tasks started until one of the running 4 finishes. The OS can assign running threads to cores, not tasks.

Comment: no I mean when I have 10 thread and some of they at this moment blocked, the core which was assigned to blocked thread will be used for another thread, is this true?

Comment: yes if you have 10 running threads, and the currently executing thread blocks, the OS will switch the blocked thread with one that is not blocked. Note that code like `while(not a.is_finished())` is not blocking code.

Comment: Also note that the OS does not run a thread until it is finished, even if the thread does not block, the OS will switch it to allow the other threads to execute.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so, just decided to clarify so as not to shoot myself in the foot

Comment: Techically, that is a _[scheduling policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Scheduling_disciplines)_ that Bob Bills is talking about there. The default scheduling policy for most modern destop, server, and mobile-device operating systems will be some form of _preemptive multitasking_ (the OS can swap threads in and out without warning) plus an algorithm to ensure that threads from competing processes each get a "fair share" of the CPU time. But other policies can be enabled, especially on special-purpose "embedded" systems.